# Postfix config for backend webservers behind a load balancer

Tags: linux, networking, email, postfix, smtp

I've two web servers (**ws1.example.com**, **ws2.example.com**) with postfix installed locally as a mail rely (using mandrillapp), user access them via **www.example.com**, which is a load balancer

On **ws1**, the configs are

**hostname**

```
ws1
```

**hostname -f**

```
ws1.example.com
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ws1.example.com ws1
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:root@example.com:abc
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

myhostname = ws1.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ws1, ws1.example.com, localhost

relayhost = [smtp.mandrillapp.com]:587

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Apparently it work, but I want to know if the above configs are set with any potential issues?

**Update**: My concern is `ws1.example.com` and `ws2.example.com` are not resolvable in my DNS.

Comment: For clarification, did you worry email *deliverability*  issues because you behind load balancer?

Comment: Because my webservers are not accessible in public Internet, and ws1.example.com are not resolvable in my DNS.

Answer (score 2):

So, As I understand here your email flowing diagram

```
wsX.example.com --> smtp.mandrillapp.com --> external mailserver
```

Now, spam checker on **external mailserver** *usually* use the last smtp server reputation to help determining if this email was spam or not. So, in this case the external mailserver just checks **smtp.mandrillapp.com** reputation ignore what happen to the email before reach **smtp.mandrillapp.com**.

But some advanced spamchecker will consider entire mailflow to determine that your email was spam or not. So, they can check if domain **wsX.example.com** was exists or not. So for safe playing I suggest you to add A record for **wsX.example.com** resolved to IP of load balancer. As alternative of previous solution, you should change `smtp_helo_name` [parameter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_helo_name) to match **example.com**.

That small step will help you to ensuring that your email will arrive in user mailbox. One of my concern about why the ws1.example.com must be resolved is the some spamchecker will check your helo name. Some excerpt from [the relevant article](https://major.io/2006/12/26/fixing-invalid-helos/)

> The common reasons why mail servers are blocked for bad HELO’s are:
>
> *Server is announcing itself as “localhost”.
>
> *Server is announcing itself as an IP address.
>
> *Server is announcing itself as a hostname that does not exist.

Comment: Yes, this is my concern. The problem is the web server is behind a load balancer and it only have internal IP assigned. So what record I should set?

Comment: ahh... load balancer and private IP. Sorry, I've missed that information. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks, so by setting `smtp_helo_name` to my load balancer DNS, will spam checker try to connect to this machine for verification? Since this load balancer only have port 80/443 enabled.

Comment: It's not necessary. You can leave smtpd port closed on your load balancer